# Calling an external webservice method from Azure function returns 401 but the same code works in a console app

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, azure-functions

I have added a web reference (WSDL) to a class library and then referenced that dll in a timer-triggered c# Azure function [(read more about azure functions)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-overview/). The class library has a class EmployeeService which calls a method from the web service (sort of a webservice wrapper). When I call the class lib method (GetEmployees) from a console application, it authenticates to the web service and returns result but when I run the azure function for the same code and creds it returns 401. Not sure what I am doing wrong here :

```
#r "MyConsult.Service.dll"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using MyConsult.Service.Service;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");   

    try
    {
         EmployeeService _empService = new EmployeeService();                  
         var emps = _empService.GetEmployees();

         int count = emps.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email)).Select(x => x.Email).Distinct().Count();
         log.Info($"employee count : {count}");       
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         log.Info($"Exception Message: {ex.Message}");
         log.Info($"Exception Stack Trace: { ex.StackTrace}");
     }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but it works after waiting for several minutes(or redeploy?). so weird. but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Your console application is likely authenticating based on service configuration settings in your app.config. For your function, you'll need to programmatically apply those settings when constructing the client/proxy.

Comment: Even I thought that could be the problem so I have hard coded the credentials. Not being read from config.

Comment: More details about the authentication mode being used as well as updated function code with the auth changes you've made would be helpful. Is that something you can provide?